# Add text over an image when uploading it in PHP

Tags: php, gd, image-manipulation

I have a pictures website like Quickmeme.com and I would like to add text over images.
I currently let the user upload the picture manually, writing the comments with Paint program in Windows which is a bad idea and I need help ...

here is the code I use for Uploading an image, I am thinking of adding a text field below the upload field so what ever the user writes in that box will be printed on the image as an imagetext ... So how can I do that with php?

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["upload"])){

        $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $file_name = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $random = rand(1, 9999999999);
        $directory = "Uploads/" . $random . $file_name;
        $time = strftime("%H:%M:%S", time());
        $date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time());

            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $directory)){
                if(mysql_query("")){
                    $query = mysql_query(""); $fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                    if(mysql_query("")){
                        header("Location: index.php");
                        exit;
                    }
                }
            }


      } ?>
```

Here is my website http://www.picturepunches.net

Comment: Add to tags image manipulation or something related. tag mysql is not relevant to this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
if (isset($_POST["upload"])) {

    $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $file_name = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $random = rand(1, 9999999999);
    $directory = "Uploads/" . $random . $file_name;
    $time = strftime("%H:%M:%S", time());
    $date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time());

    switch (strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))) {
        case "jpg" :
            $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
            break;
        case "gif" :
            $im = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
            break;
        case "png" :
            $im = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
            break;

        default :
            trigger_error("Error Bad Extention");
            exit();
            break;
    }

    $font = 'verdana.ttf';
    $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
    $red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
    // Add some shadow to the text
    imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 11, 20, $grey, $font, $date);
    imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 10, 35, $grey, $font, $time);
    imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 10, 50, $red, $font, $random);

    // imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);

    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $directory)) {
        if (mysql_query("")) {
            $query = mysql_query("");
            $fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            if (mysql_query("")) {
                header("Location: index.php");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

[image][image]

```
           Uploaded                               Final
```

Answer (score 2):

First, check if you have the GD extension installed, next,

Use the GD functions

```
//Loading the file
$rImg = ImageCreateFromJPEG("MyPicture.jpg");

//Font Color (black in this case)
$color = imagecolorallocate($rImg, 0, 0, 0);

//x-coordinate of the upper left corner. 
$xPos = 100;
//y-coordinate of the upper left corner. 
$yPos = 30;

//Writting the picture
imagestring($rImg,5,$xPos,$yPos,"My text in the picture",$color);

//The new file with the text
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($rImg, NULL, 100);
```

you can use this tutorial

http://blog.doh.ms/2008/02/12/adding-text-to-images-in-real-time-with-php/